# Number of sequences $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ which are solutions to an equation

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following Proposition:

**Proposition 1**: *The number of sequences $(x_1, \dots, x_n)\in \mathbb{N}^n$ which are solutions to the equation $x_1 + \dots + x_n = p$ is equal to $\binom{p+n-1}{p}$*.

I have already proven the following Proposition:

**Proposition 2**: *Let $n$ and $p$ be two positive integers and let $B$ be a totally ordered set of cardinality $p$. Then the number of increasing sequences $(c_1 \leq c_2 \leq \dots \leq c_n)$, of length $n$ made of elements of $B$ is equal to $\binom{p+n-1}{n}  = \binom{p+n-1}{p-1}$.*

Now I tried to understand the following proof of Proposition 1 which uses Proposition 2.

**Proof of Proposition 1**:

Let $x = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ be a solution to the equation. Let us associate with it the increasing sequence $y= (y_1, \dots, y_n)$ as follows:

$y_1 = 1 + x_1; y_2 = 1+x_1+x_2, \dots, y_{n-1}= 1 + x_1 + \dots + x_{n-1}$

$y_n = 1 + x_1 + \dots + x_n = 1 + p$

We thus have $1 \leq y_1 \leq y_2 \leq \dots y_{n-1} \leq 1+p$.

Conversely if $y$ is such a sequence, we define $x= (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ by:

$x_n = 1+p-y_{n-1}, x_{n-1} = y_{n-1} - y_{n-2}, \dots , x_2 = y_2 - y_1, x_1 = y_1 - 1$

This sequence satisfies : $x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n = p$

We can see that there is a bijection between the solution of equation $x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n = p$ and increasing sequences of length $n-1$ taken from $\{1, \dots , 1+p\}$. It thus follows from Proposition 2 that there are $\binom{(p+1)+(n-1)-1}{n-1}= \binom{p+n-1}{n-1}= \binom{p+n-1}{p}$ solutions.

**Questions**:

1. Why are we allowed to use Proposition 2 if we do not have a totally ordered set?
2. I do understand the single steps. But - intuitively - it is not clear to me how every possible combination of the solution to the given equation was covered. The way $(y_1, \dots, y_n)$ was defined seems random to me.

Comment: "*Why are we allowed to use proposition 2 if we do not have a totally ordered set?*"  I don't understand this question... We said "*Let $B$ be a totally ordered set*"... where do you see us using proposition 2 with a set that is not totally ordered?

Comment: In proposition $1$ the set is $\mathbb{N}$, which is certainly totally ordered.

Comment: @saulspatz If the ordered set $B$ was $\mathbb{N}$ then the cardinality of $B$ would be $\infty$. Then the binomial coefficient cannot be calculated. What am I missing?

Comment: @MyGanton that there are indeed infinitely many increasing sequences... it gave the correct result.

Comment: @JMoravitz As I see it $(y_1, \dots, y_{n-1})$ is not necessarily totally ordered.

Comment: Well okay, it's actually the set of integers from $1$ to $p$, but that's totally ordered, too.  It's clear that none of the $x_i$ can be greater than $p$.

Comment: You could just as well have had $B$ be a set of students where they are arranged by height or by age or however else you chose to totally order the students... Part of the point is that we don't actually care what the objects are nor do we care how exactly they are sorted amongst each other... just that we *can* sort them.

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, I agree on that. But what if there are $x_i$ and $x_j$ which could be equal? Then the set wouldn't be totally ordered, right?

Comment: Note that the set $\{1,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,5\}$ is a five element set which can be more concisely written as $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.  If they were equal... then they are equal... and not needing to appear in the list more than once.

Comment: It's the set from which the elements are drawn which must be totally ordered.

Comment: I see it now! But what remains unclear to me is the way we defined $(y_1, \dots, y_n)$. This is *one* way to define such a sequence which then satisfies the given equation at the beginning. But what if there were other such sequences? Or won't there be any other such sequences because of the bijectivity?